# weird jQuery UI Slider behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm developing a simple one page website and I'm integrating the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/). The website I'm integrating it in is : [Website](http://rolandgroza.com/projects/chaoscod3r/).

It seems like I'm having a little problem with the slider. If you look closely at the slider when navigating with the left and right arrow ( or the left and right keyboard keys ) you will notice that when going backward, before the last step, the min range jumps ahead the handle with a few pixels ( the background image ).

And also the animate property attached to the handle it doesn't work when using the mouse cursor to move the handle, per say the handle is in position 0 and you click on the last position, normally it should animate to the last position but it jumps there.

Could someone tell me how to fix these bugs ? I tried working on the CSS for the first problem but it doesn't seem to be because of that.

Comment: at this instance, consider avoiding jQueryUI's slider, and you may implement a custom one.

Comment: Your website is crashing my browser.. Can you narrow down what you want and set up a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Vega - Why would it crash your site ? I don't see a reason. Maybe because the database was updated, that's the only thing that might slow down the website, it updates every two hours.

Comment: @Roland My browser got crashed trying to open your site.. It showed me "Stop Script". I didn't try to debug.. It is easier If you can set it up in fiddle

Comment: @Vega -  I cannot do that, there is a lot of MySQL and PHP running there, there is no way I can make that work in a fiddle.

Comment: @Roland I will try to check it from Home.. I can't run it from office >.<

Comment: I am unable to access your website with FF12, but from your description it sounds like you are running into the single animation buffer problem with all jQuery animations. You have to cancel the previous animation .stop() before applying a new one. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: The website seems up and running now... will take a look at what's going on.

Comment: @ChristopherSmithson - This isn't just a simple jQuery animation, it's probably inside the core of jQuery UI since that's what I'm using. Also I'm not using any jQuery animations in my script, only the jQuery UI uses I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "min range jumps ahead the handle" - I've reduced the bug here: http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/Gd5dn/

   This is a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7109) in `jQuery.animate()` when animating non-pixel values; Slider uses percentages. Before animating, jQuery converts the element's starting value (in pixels) into the end value's units, and assigns this non-px starting value to the element (lines 8601-8605 in jQuery 1.7.2 (unminified)).

   The calculation is flawed for small end values (like 0%), and so the range's starting width is larger than what it should be.

   I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/808) with a fix; the same fix can be applied to the current stable version of jQuery.

   **Update:** You can find a plugin that fixes this bug (for jQuery 1.7.2) here: http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/zbkQX/

   Copy from (at the top)

   ```
   // Start jQuery.animate() fix
   ```

   to (before the test code)

   ```
   // End jQuery.animate() fix
   ```

   It should work if you paste this code into your plugins.js.
2. "it should animate to the last position but it jumps there" - this is because the Slider and jPages plugins are connected with circular callbacks.

   When the user clicks on the slider, Slider triggers a `slide` event then animates the handle and range. The `slide` event handler calls jPages to change to the new page. jPages calls its assigned callback function, which passes the current page number back to Slider. Slider sets its value and starts to animate the handle/range.

   After the `slide` event, Slider goes back to animating the handle and range (which is actually the second time it is animating). Slider calls `.stop(1, 1)` on the elements before animating, which causes the first animation to stop and jump immediately to its end value. (The second `.animate()` does nothing since the elements are already in the correct position.)

   (I hope that made sense :-) )

   I suggest adding logic in the jPages callback to call Slider with the new page number only if the trigger isn't originally from Slider.

   **Update:** I think you'll need to update both callbacks:

   For Slider:

   ```
   slide: function(event, ui) {
       if (!self.paging) {
           self.paging = true;
           $(self.shop_navigation_class).jPages(ui.value);
           self.paging = false;
       }
   }
   ```

   For jPages:

   ```
   callback: function(pages) {
       var data = {
           current_page: pages.current,
           total_pages: pages.count
       }
       self.set_local_storage_data(self.data_key, JSON.stringify(data));
       if (!self.paging) {
           self.paging = true;
           $(self.shop_slider_class).slider("value", pages.current);
           self.paging = false;
       }
   }
   ```

   Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: So, the animation was in fact a bug, I see. Is there a fix for it yet ? If so what would that be, the updated version of jQuery UI or something else ? And withe the second part, you're right, I was thinking that might be a problem but I tried it without adding the callbacks and with the same result. So what would you have me do, can you show me how that logic would look ?

Comment: Indeed, it works :) I see that the bug fix is a rewrite of the `.animate()` method, have you written that yourself ? Because it's in fact pretty neat :) And as for the second solution, wouldn't there be some logic without involving another variable ? I was using something like this before but I also declared it in the main function. Thanks for the solutions and if you don't mind, do you think I should use jQuery UI in this situation or should I use a custom built of my own ?

Comment: @Roland Almost all of the `.animate()` code is copied from the official jQuery source; the only thing I changed is between `// XXX start fix` and `// XXX end fix` (and I defined a new variable a few lines above that). For the second solution, you can edit the Slider and/or jPages code to do the same thing without the boolean flag, but it would be much more complicated. I think as long as jQuery UI is saving you more time than you are spending adapting/fixing it to do what you want, then it is worth using.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is probably to *just not use jQueryUI's slider*.

Having looked at your code it looks like you're easily competent enough at JS and CSS to replicate its appearance and core behaviour yourself, and make it work exactly how you want it to.

Comment: I have to agree. You/or someone else has created a lot of JS code already, so not going to be that hard to create the functionality to replicate the slider effect.

Comment: So I should try going for another solution rather than using jQuery UI ? But I must mention that at different screen sizes the maximum steps change, depending on the size.

Comment: @Roland that sounds like even more reason to write it yourself.  You could stil rely on jQuery to handle the thumb animation, of course...

Comment: OK, well I can use CSS3 animations, I don't think I really need jQuery for that. But I have one question, what would be the logic of this ? I have the same width for the slider at any screen size, so only the steps width modify, this means I need to calculate in percentage the width of each step and the sliding will have that calculated width, and so on ? Should I use inputs or divs ? What else do you advise ?